# API To Object Mapping in PHP

Tags: php, orm

We have so many ORM (Object Relational Mapping) software:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#PHP

How about API to Object mapping?

We don't use database, but API. So all data come from REST APIs.

Classic ORMs do not seem to handle that. Looks like I should do my own using Zend's code generator: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.codegenerator.html

Comment: what do you mean by API to Object mapping?

Comment: are they REST APIs that you have control over?